# Alternative php silex template

Tags: php, symfony, twig, template-engine, silex

Lately I've been using a [template manager for silex](https://github.com/kherge-abandoned/php-silex-template), but I've noticed that it's been abandoned and no longer works for newer versions of silex. Here's an example code of what it does (it can be seen on its [GitHub page](https://github.com/kherge-abandoned/php-silex-template)):

```
<?php

use Herrera\Template\TemplateServiceProvider;
use Silex\Application;

$app = new Application();

$app->register(new TemplateServiceProvider(), array(
    'template.dir' => '/path/to/dir',
    'template.dir' => array(
        '/path/to/dir1',
        '/path/to/dir2',
        '/path/to/dir3',
    )
));

$app['template.engine']->render('test.php');
```

So, what it exactly does is that it renders the file you give, and you can also give other parameters to send it to the file before rendering it... It was very useful to me, but as I said, it's been abandoned and it no longer works with newer versions of Silex.
So, what I'm asking is: is it a good alternative of this that works with newer versions? Should I downgrade my Silex in order to be able to use this? Or is it very hard to try to "create" a system for being able to use this?

I've heard about [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/), but it doesn't really convince me because it doesn't seem to be convenient with what I want to achieve.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have the same result just extending the twig loader (Twig_Loader_Filesystem).

```
$app['twig.loader.filesystem'] = $app->share(
    $app->extend('twig.loader.filesystem', function($loader, $app) {
        $loader->addPath('/path/to/dir1');
        $loader->addPath('/path/to/dir2');
        $loader->addPath('/path/to/dir3');
        return $loader;
    }
);
```

Then you just use twig as always. `$app['twig']->render('template.twig', array(...));`

The filesystem loader will look for templates in */path/to/dir1*, and if they dont exists it will fallback to look for them in */path/to/dir2* and so on.

If you insist in using a pure PHP templating engine you can do it with the Symfony Templating Component:

Install with composer **symfony/templating** and then register the service:

```
use Symfony\Component\Templating\PhpEngine;
use Symfony\Component\Templating\TemplateNameParser;
use Symfony\Component\Templating\Loader\FilesystemLoader;

$app['templating'] = $app->share(function() {
    $loader = new FilesystemLoader(array(
        '/path/to/dir1',
        '/path/to/dir2',
        '/path/to/dir3',
    ));
    $nameParser = new TemplateNameParser();
    $templating = new PhpEngine($nameParser, $loader);
    return $templating;
});
```

Then you just use this engine as `$app['templating']->render('template.php', array(...));`

Comment: Oh, thanks! That will really help me out, it looks like it will be okay for my project. Thanks again!! :D

Comment: Be careful with the Symfony Templating Component, [it will probably be abandoned as well](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/12897).